# Catel: change look and feel of error message

Tags: validation, look-and-feel, catel

Good day!

How can I change a look and feel of Catel's error message?

[image: Image here]

1. Change a language of string "The following warnings and/or errors found (hover to view);
2. How can I force validation on every TextChanged event?
3. I want to change field highlighting look. How can I do that? Make highlighted in red not only field's border, also background of field, for exemple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/3) Create a custom style based on [this one](https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/e15d79c8ef107bb84d4acd26ca0a9b55617ffb9b/src/Catel.MVVM/Catel.MVVM.NET40/Themes/InfoBarMessageControl.generic.xaml).

2) Every time the property changes  on the view model, Catel will re-validate your view model. So it's important to update your binding. You can do that by something like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```